# Angular 5 attribute directive add mat-ripple to host element

Tags: angular, angular-directive

How can I add the `mat-ripple` directive to the host element of a custom directive I've created? The point is to have `mat-ripple` automagically added to any element I add `my-custom-directive` too.

So if I add `<button my-custom-directive>Button</button>` to the template it should be rendered as `<button my-custom-directive mat-ripple mat-ripple-color="#000">Button</button>`  without having to type all of that out every time I use `my-custom-directive`. As an example look at how `mat-raised-button` works. You simply add that directive and you get `mat-ripple` with it. I want to duplicate that with my own buttons.

This doesn't work.

**HTML**

```xml
<button my-custom-directive>Button</button>
```

**Directive**

```js
@Directive({
  selector: ['appMyCustomDirective']
})
export class MyCustomDirective implements AfterViewInit {
  constructor(
    private renderer: Renderer,
    private element: ElementRef
  ) { }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.renderer.setElementAttribute(this.element.nativeElement, 'mat-ripple', '');
    this.renderer.setElementAttribute(this.element.nativeElement, 'mat-ripple-color', '#000000');
  }
}
```

I also tried injecting `MatRipple` into the directive and calling `MatRipple.launch(...)` but this creates a ripple effect that isn't constrained inside the button and doesn't apply the same colors as when I add `mat-ripple` directly to the element via the template.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was able to achieve my goal by providing `MatRipple` in the directive and manually launching combined with some styles.

**Directive**

```js
@Directive({
  selector: '[app-outline-button]',
  providers: [ MatRipple ]
})
export class OutlineButtonDirective implements AfterViewInit {
  constructor(
    private ripple: MatRipple
  ) { }

  @HostListener('mousedown', [ '$event' ]) onmousedown(event) {
    this.ripple.launch(event.x, event.y);
  }
}
```

I then had to give the button `overflow: hidden;` style to prevent the ripple from expanding beyond the button.

Finally to use my directive which auto-magically includes mat-ripple directive:

```xml
<button app-outline-button>Button</button>
```

Comment: You also must set `position: relative`.